# Default Scheduler Exists - how to use a multithreaded Qt app in another project?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, qt, sdl-2

I am working on a VS2015 solution that integrates 2 stand-alone projects - an SDL2 game, and a Qt4 Application. At a certain point in the SDL game, I want the Qt application to launch, do it's job, and close, giving control back to the game.

I am able to run the Qt application from the game; however, on closing it throws a default_scheduler_exists() error. Another error that comes up is "ASSERT failure in QCoreApplicaton; "there should be only one application object." "

How do I fix this? I tried running the game and app on seperate threads, but that did not solve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you launch the application from the game? Is it in the same process?

Comment: Yes, I am calling the main() function of the application from within the game

Comment: The game itself uses Qt, then, and somehow both try to use the same copy of Qt. Don't do that. If a `QApplication` exists, you don't want to create a new one; use the existing one via `qApp`. Another common problem I see is that of passing invalid arguments to `main`.